# how to access a javascript property via jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Declared a java script like follows

```
var formData= new function () {
      this.HasFormInputChanged = false;
}
```

For the Property HasFormInputChanged i am able to assign/retrieve the value in either way

```
$(formData).attr('HasFormInputChanged')

   Or

$(formData)[0].HasFormInputChanged
```

Is it possible to retrieve the property value as like below

```
$(formData).HasFormInputChanged
```

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: It's better to use `.prop()` than `.attr()` to assign or retrieve properties values.

Comment: Since I am able to access like formData.HasFormInputChanged, in that same way i tried to use like that.

Answer (score 0):

No. Unless you modify the jQuery source code.

Answer (score 0):

Custom objects are not HTMLElementNodes and cannot be treated as such.